# Why is adding multiple images to a gallery object not working at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, image-gallery

I am creating a gallery where you can upload multiple images via  form.

The form is nested inside another form and when that is submitted it should create the gallery with the attached images inside it. When I check the output I get this which means its not submitting the correct images to the gallery object at all:

```
Parameters: {
    "utf8"=>"✓", 
    "authenticity_token"=>"BJhkDx7rCRMIlXQ6T9FskXZe7+fdYxj0qm+VnCaC51w=", 
    "book"=>{ 
        "jacket_cover" =>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001025d3128 
        @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/RackMultipart20140918-47766-1g9kyas>, @original_filename="559a7a477253d58f891f8e852162dfac.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"book[jacket_cover]\"; filename=\"559a7a477253d58f891f8e852162dfac.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
        "title"=>"zd szw wrwr", 
        "synopsis"=>"<p>cfdcrgcgrere</p>\r\n", 
        "body"=>"<p>rccgregrrgerereg</p>\r\n", 
        "age"=>"19", 
        "publisher"=>"Dove books", 
        "author_attributes"=>{
            "name"=>"zsdxfrrwg", 
            "biography"=>"<p>exffwfwefewewf</p>\r\n"}, 
        "gallery_attributes"=>{
            "images_attributes"=>{
            "0"=>{
                "file"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001025d20e8 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/RackMultipart20140918-47766-tk1rdb>, @original_filename="23ebb202a3655c6d0947251cce8625b6.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"book[gallery_attributes][images_attributes][0][file][]\"; filename=\"23ebb202a3655c6d0947251cce8625b6.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001025d1ff8 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/RackMultipart20140918-47766-j3ji7c>, @original_filename="559a7a477253d58f891f8e852162dfac.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"book[gallery_attributes][images_attributes][0][file][]\"; filename=\"559a7a477253d58f891f8e852162dfac.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]
            }
            }
        }
    }, "commit"=>"Create Book"

}
```

The books_controller handles the submission of the gallery with the images in it:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json
  def index
    @books = Book.order('created_at DESC').all
  end

  # GET /books/1
  # GET /books/1.json
  def show
    # @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book = Book.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @gallery = @book.gallery
  end

  # GET /books/new
  def new
    @book = Book.new
    @book.build_author
    @gallery = @book.build_gallery 
    @gallery.images.build
  end

  # GET /books/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /books
  # POST /books.json
  def create
    #raise params.inspect
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    #binding.pry

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /books/1
  # PATCH/PUT /books/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /books/1
  # DELETE /books/1.json
  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  # Get authors
  # def reviews
  # @book = Book.friendly.find(params[:id])
  # @reviews = @movie.reviews

  #   respond_to do |format|
  #     format.html { render 'reviews/index' } # index.html.erb
  #     format.json { render json: @movies }
  #   end
  # end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_book
      # @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      @book = Book.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :synopsis, :body, :age, :publisher, :jacket_cover, author_attributes: [:name,:biography], gallery_attributes: [:name, :book_id ] )    
    end
end
```

book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :jacket_cover, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :jacket_cover, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    validates :jacket_cover, :title, :slug, :synopsis, :body, :age, :publisher, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :title

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

    belongs_to :author
    has_one :gallery
    has_many :stories

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery

    scope :available, ->{ where(available: true) }
    scope :unavailable, ->{ where(available: [nil, false]) }

end
```

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :gallery

    has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

gallery.rb

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :books
    has_many :images
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

galleries_controller.rb

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gallery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
  end

  def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @images = @gallery.images
  end

  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
    #@gallery.images.build
    # @images = @gallery.build_images 
    # @gallery.images.build
  end

  def edit
    @gallery.images.build
  end

  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
    @image = Image.create()
    #@gallery.images.build 

    respond_to do |format| 
      if @gallery.save 
      format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' } 
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @gallery } 
      else 
      format.html { render action: 'new' } 
      format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
      end 
    end 
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @gallery.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to galleries_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_gallery
      @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    end

    def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :book_id, :image)
      #params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :book_id, :images[], images_attributes: [:id, :file []])
      #params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :book_id, :images[images_attributes: [:file]])
      # params.require(:gallery).permit(:name, :book_id, images_attributes: [:id, :image[:file]])
    end
end
```

Added form in here that submits the gallery of images:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@book, :html => { :multipart => true } ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <div id="image" class="field">
      <h3>Add the book image here</h3>
      <div class="single-file">
        <div class="file_upload">
           <%= f.file_field :jacket_cover %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="title" class="field">
      <h3>Add the title</h3>
      <%= f.input :title %>
    </div>
    <div id="synopsis" class="field">
      <h3>Add the book synopsis</h3>
      <%= f.input :synopsis, :as => :ckeditor, :label => false, :input_html => {  :ckeditor => { :toolbar => 'Full', :height => 400 } } %>
    </div>
    <div id="body" class="field">
      <h3>Add the book body summary here</h3>
      <%= f.input :body, :as => :ckeditor, :label => false, :input_html => {  :ckeditor => { :toolbar => 'Full', :height => 400 } } %>
    </div>
    <div id="age" class="field">
      <h3>Add the book age group</h3>
      <%= f.input :age, collection: [['3-7', '3-7'],['7-11', '7-11'],['11-14', '11-14']], prompt: "Select age range" %>
    </div>
    <div id="publisher" class="field">
      <h3>Who published the book</h3>
      <%= f.input :publisher %>
    </div>

    <div id="school" class="field">
      <h3>Schools reading this book (add the name and full address of the school)</h3>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :schools, :wrapper => 'inline' do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'school_fields', :f => builder %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add school', f, :schools, :render_options => {:wrapper => 'inline' }, :class => 'fa fa-plus' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <%#= f.select( :author_id, Author.all.map {|u| [u.name,u.id]}, {:include_blank => false, prompt: "No Author"} ) %>
  <div id="author-inputs">
    <h3>Add author</h3>
    <%#= link_to 'New Author', new_author_path, :remote => true, :id => "new_author_link" %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :author, :wrapper => 'inline' do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'author_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :gallery do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'galleries/form', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I check in the db console I cannot see any images inside the gallery when I search Gallery.all

I have created a gist file with all the necessary info in it.

Can anyone shed any light into this for me at all?

Comment: did you add accepts_nested_attributes_for :images in your Book model?

Comment: you also don't have images_attributes in your permit_params, what are the models. Do you have has_many :galleries, which has_many :images?, so it has book has_many through?

Comment: Can I see your gallery model and controller?

Comment: navinspm Ivan Shamatov I have edited the doc

Comment: My book and gallery models are right I think?

Comment: Do you really mean for :books to be plural inside of Gallery model?

Comment: It has to be because there are more than 1 book

Comment: I feel like there's something wrong in that association between gallery and book, but I can't seem to put my finger on it...  What do your gallery and book migrations look like?

Comment: The schema for gallery and book has the correct association ids like so: galleries table: book_id and books table: gallery_id

Comment: Only one table should be keeping a reference to the other. Specifically, the side of the one to many relation that is the many should be keeping the relation to its one.

Comment: Do you host this project on Github? There is too much going on in your question. Probably easiest is to test drive this.

Comment: Could you please post your form as well?

Comment: Added the form in now

Comment: Try `<%= f.file_field :jacket_cover, multiple: true %>`

Comment: Thats not part of the gallery its just the jacket cover, which will be completely different to the gallery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is with your parent form and model relationship.

In your book model you should have `belongs_to :gallery` instead of `has_one :gallery`. Also check your database. `books` Table should have `gallery_id`. As a database concept belongs_to should have parent table id. So model should be :

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :jacket_cover, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :jacket_cover, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    validates :jacket_cover, :title, :slug, :synopsis, :body, :age, :publisher, presence: true
    validates_uniqueness_of :title

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]

    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :gallery
    has_many :stories

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery

    scope :available, ->{ where(available: true) }
    scope :unavailable, ->{ where(available: [nil, false]) }

end
```

and your gallery model should look like :

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :books
    has_many :images
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :books
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

Your parent model in form should be `gallery` model instead of `book`. And also make required changes in your gallery controller.

Comment: I dont see how this helps at all??

Comment: Hey Nitin so `<%= simple_form_for(@book, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>` should be `<%= simple_form_for(@gallery, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>`? When you say make required changes in gallery controller do you mean take what has been added in books controller and make that work for the gallery?

Comment: Yes You should have gallery as parent model. So save gallery instead of book and put all logic in gallery controller. You also have to change permit params in your controller

Comment: really? but the whole point is that the person is adding a book not a gallery, the gallery is a subsidary of the book the book is the most important part of the whole thing. If its the gallery then surely that logic is wrong? The process is: you login, the go to add book, you add the book details add some images in a book gallery that is attached to the book and then save the form and basically there should be a book with a gallery within it.

Comment: Am I completely not getting this then or is it all wrong?

Comment: I am not able to understand Your flow and requirement properly. If you can wr9ite it like. Gallery has many images. A book has many images. And now can you write relation between book and gallery then I can help to solve the problem easily

Comment: Hi Nitin, So a gallery has many images, a gallery belongs to a book and images belong to gallery which has many images. When you publish the book the images attached to the gallery are saved inside the gallery and the gallery relation is attached to the book because the book can only have 1 image at any one time.

Comment: Okay so each book have it's own gallery or a gallery can have multiple type books. Also You said one book has exactly one image

Comment: Yes so each book has a gallery and yes if its needed a gallery can have multiple type books. No in my gallery model a gallery has many images and in image model image belongs to gallery. The issue I am having is that the images are not being added into the params array for gallery_attributes as a set of images in an array so I can access them all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61670/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-nitin-verma).